# How to force auto reload of Flask in code?

Tags: python, session, flask, server, bokeh

I want to render a session of a bokeh plot on a flask server. The problem I have is, that the generated script tag of that session only produces the plot after I reload the flask server. 
The reload takes place by saving the server file.

Is there a way to force this event in the underlying python code? Something like Flask.reload()?

Answer (score 0):

My tip is: create a new route to process the information you want and make a request via javascript (jquery/ajax) to get the data and popularize the charts.

Javascript is responsible for performing this type of action. After a template is rendered, only JS can make changes in the DOM (no more python responsibility).

Comment: I already realised the session in a react application. Hereby I fetched the script tag that the flask server generated and added it to my react app. But the error remains the same.